# Texturing with Slick Library?

Tags: java, textures, lwjgl

So I have 2 issues.

1. I have a 16x16 image that works fine...
   When I say the info the image size is 16x16
   and the texture size is 16x16

I have a 100x100 image that when I say the info...
The image size is 100x100 but,
The texture size is 128x128...

I don't know why this is but it screws everything up!

1. The 16x16 is pixely (What I want) but I want to display it
   on a 100x100 surface and it blurs it! I don't want it blurred
   I want it to look like the original. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a power of 2 texture when using basic OpenGL.